# Avatar Cordova InappBrowser dropbox chooser unable to close window

Tags: android, cordova, webview, dropbox, inappbrowser

I can't get the Dropbox chooser to work with Cordova on android i get "unable to close window" i don't know if its window.open or window.close that aren't working correctly.
The webview have settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
Are there any good worke around?

Comment: To be clear, is the actual message: "Unable to close this window. Please close it manually and return to the previous site."? In the web view, does the "parent" window, i.e., the page where the user clicked the Chooser button, still exist, or has it been replaced by the Chooser itself?